# Which preposition to use in “communication [over, by, through, via, with] email”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, business-language

Which of these is most correct, and why?

1. Our team kept in constant communication **over** email.
2. Our team kept in constant communication **by** email.
3. Our team kept in constant communication **through** email.
4. Our team kept in constant communication **via** email.
5. Our team kept in constant communication **with** email.

Comment: "by texting, instead of"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with email, it's important to remember that it is short for "electronic mail".  When trying to find the right word to use with email, drop the "e" and just consider "mail".  If you do this, then "Our team kept in constant communication **by** mail" is the only appropriate choice.  Thus, by should also be used with email.

Comment: The word that is usually used with "mail" is COMPLETELY AND ABSOLUTELY **IRRELEVANT** to the question of what word to use with "email". *Email* has long ago acquired its own independent existence; just like every other word in the dictionary, its *etymology* does not and cannot govern its usage.

Comment: @Marthaª Very strongly disagree. I cannot use email in any way I could not use mail, and vice versa.

Comment: @tchrist: try substituting "mail" into "Nobody ever emails me" and *then* tell me that "mail" and "email" are used identically.

Comment: @Marthaª Um, that’s the normal way to say it though. “Nobody ever mails me” means that my inbox is empty.

Comment: @tchrist: is this an across-the-pond thing? I would never in my life say something as preposterous-sounding as "nobody ever mails me" unless it was followed by, say, "cookies".

Comment: @Marthaª Perhaps so, since unless it were destined for the most inveterate of muggles, I couldn’t imagine **ever** using *was* for *were* in an *unless* protasis whose apodosis contained *would* or *should*.  But I don’t know what preposterous pond you’re referring to: mayhap the channelly one across from which they use ***courriel*** in lieu of ***mail***? Me, I mail people all the time; if you would be so kind as to supply me with your RFC-5322—compliant address, I’d be more than delighted to demonstrate. Or perhaps you’re just using some form of youthful slang with which I am unacquainted.

Answer (score 16):

I'd go with "via". It wins the "Google war" by a large margin, although as we know that's not always indicative of anything.

- communication *over* email - this could be interpreted as, the subject of the communication is email.
- communication *by* email - I first wanted to parse this as the email is the thing doing the communicating.
- communication *through* email - this could work; I think the only reason it sounds more awkward than "via" is that we're not used to it.
- communication *via* email - this says exactly what you want, i.e. email is the method used for communication.
- communication *with* email - this sounds like you're talking to the email.

Comment: -1.  I'm not sure where you get that connotation with the word "by".  By often implies a means.  "I came by car."  "How did you talk to him?  By phone."  "The letter came by post."

Comment: @Eric: obviously it *doesn't* mean the email is doing the communicating, but there is an initial disconnect that causes my brain, at least, to try to force the sentence into the more usual meaning of "by". I know we say "by phone" and "by post" all the time, but we *don't* say "by email", at least in my corner of the world.

Comment: Does "via" really indicate a method? I thought it indicated an intermediary location, as in "I travelled from London to Rome via Paris."

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick is correct; "via" is a preposition that describes routing through places. "By" is the correct preposition for describing a method used; the odious phrase "via email" is an example of the MBA-speak that has infested the English-speaking world in recent years, nearly as bad as the use of "resource" to mean "person".

Answer (score 5):

A couple more distinct alternatives for you to think about:

- Our team constantly communicated by email.
- Our team kept in constant communication using email.

Comment: I like the suggestion of *using*. (Note that *by* is one of the options Ricket asked about.)

Comment: @Martha: my 'by' sentence has a different structure around the 'by'.

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't notice that.