# via or by - which one is correct to denote by means of

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Communication [over, by, through, via, with] email”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/communication-over-by-through-via-with-email)

Which one is more formal - via or by?

Send via email

or

Send by email

Also, same in case of...

Notify via email

or

Notify by email

or

Notify through email

Comment: Check previous questions, this has most likely been already answered.

Comment: Some people do think that `via` should generally be used only to refer to the route, not the means. So you run the risk that those people will think you're "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

Both would be found in a formal context and which you use is a matter of personal choice. I prefer the native preposition because the unnecessary use of Latin words in a modern context,, such as one that talks about emails, sounds out of place.

Comment: Thanks Barrie. Is "by" apply for the second part as well?

Comment: @krishnajay: 'Notify be email'? Yes.